# How does $this->print = $render work in Drupal?

Tags: php, oop, drupal-7, rendering

I understand that this is object oriented, and that you are essentially passing the value of the [print] cell from the [this] array into a separate variable called $render.

But, does this automatically cause the information to be displayed on screen?

see code for reference:

```
  public function setPrintRender(array $render) {
    $this->print = $render;
  }
```

Or is this information going to respectfully stay quietly in that variable until some other process grabs it and then displays it on the screen?

**UPDATE**

So, maybe this part of the code is what actually prints the info?

```
  public function build() {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($this->panes as $pane) {
      $output[$pane->getId()] = $this->buildPane($pane);
    }
    if ($render = $this->pos->getState()->getPrintRender()) {
      $output[] = array(
        '#prefix' => '<div class="element-invisible"><div class="pos-print">',
        '#suffix' => '</div></div>',
        'print' => $render,
      );
    }
    return $output;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't cause it to be rendered.

A variable `$render` is being passed into `setPrintRender()` which then sets it to an internal variable called `$this->print`.

This is known as a setter. You will generally have a getter and setter method for every publicly available variable.

Comment: Oh, I see. So where is the command that eventually prints this to screen?

Comment: I'm not familiar with drupal, but your updated example does look like the place that it outputs.`getPrintRender` is the getter for the classes `$this->print` variable.

Comment: Thanks, mkaatman! So, I changed the $this->print = $render; to $this->print = ''; in the top part, and that effectively stopped the pop-up from appearing with the information (which is what I was trying to do.)